# eosinophil question

Tags: cell-biology, homework, immunology

Which of the following statement(s) is/are incorrect?

A. All cells of the immune system originate in the Bone Marrow

B. Lymphoid progenitor cells originate from a pluripotent stem cell

C. B cells develop in the thymus

D. Eosinophils are highly phagocytic

E. Both (b) and (d)

F. Both (c) and (d)

I suspect the answer is E, but I'm not entirely sure how phagocytic eosinophils are (I think it's pretty low b/c they mainly degranulate)

Reasoning:

A-correct because all immune cells originate from hematopoietic stem cells (HSC) from the bone marrow (BM).

B-wrong bc the HSC only gives rise to blood cells and is not pluripotent

C-Correct, B cells are differentiated in the BM, but mature in the thymus.

D-Wrong??, My lecture notes say that eosinophils are granulocytes (their main function), but google says they also phagocytose, so my conclusion is that they are NOT highly phagocytic.

->>> answer = E?

Comment: Did you google any of this? If so, what did you find out? (Showing your research - not just what you suspect - is pretty much required in questions here, or it will be closed as a homework question.)